# Insert array into database

Tags: php, database, arrays, zend-framework

I'm using zend to insert fields into a database like so

```
$row->title = $title;
$row->description = $description
etc etc
```

I want the next line to be:

```
$row->images = $images;    // where $images is an array
```

Then I'm calling the save function:

```
$row->save;
```

Is there anyway I can input that array?

I was going to loop through it but that won't work as I'd have to save the row X times where X is the amount of images and that just doesn't fit with the way zend wants me to insert data into the db.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There's not an easy way to do it, but one way you could handle it (which I've done before) is make images a text field, and then json_encode($images) before inserting it.

You'd of course have to json_decode it when you got it back out, and you can't really index like that, but it's a thought.

Alternatively, you might rethink your problem here. You could always have another table which stores the images, and has a reference id back to your first table.

Comment: Yeah, Database normalization is usually the better way to go. Though with huge datasets noSQL seems to be the way to go, so yeah...

Answer (score 0):

You can also store them as `serialized` value and use them after `unserializing`

`serialze($array)` and `unserialize($array)`